# Map Filter and Fold in C++

Tags: java, c++11, functional-programming

I have a problem that normally would be well suited for Java streams, but I'm currently using c++11.

The way I would solve this problem in Java is:

```
int solution = myList.stream() //myList is an arraylist of MyClass
    .mapToInt(MyClass::GetInt)
    .sum();
```

After exploring the c++ standard library a little, I have learned that 
`std::transform` and `std::accumulate` exist.

My only problem is that `std::transform` seems like it can only map from type `T` to type `T`, where I need to map from type `T` to type `V` (integer), before I can accumulate.

Ideally I'd like to be able to chain this logic together instead of having temporary arrays storing the intermediate results of each step.

Is there an idiomatic c++11 way to accomplish this?

Comment: Read the documentation for `accumulate` again. And then again.

Comment: "seems like it can only map from type T to type T" - are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::transform` can transform to a different type, but you don't even need that here. You can just use `std::accumulate` with a custom operation, like this:

```
int solution = std::accumulate(
  begin(myList), end(myList), 0,
  [](int v, const MyClass &c) { return v + c.GetInt(); }
);
```

An alternative way, pretty close to the Java example you've posted, would be to use the [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) library:

```
int solution = boost::accumulate(
  myList | boost::adaptors::transformed(boost::mem_fn(&MyClass::GetInt)),
  0
);
```